# Enable Keep-Alive setting in Dropwizard configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, jetty, load-balancing, dropwizard, elastic-load-balancer

I am observing a lot of 5xx errors on my Application load balancer logs. I have a dropwizard application listening to HTTP requests behind the ALB. On reading about ALB, I found AWS documentation says: -

> If you use HTTP and HTTPS listeners, we recommend that you enable the HTTP keep-alive option for your instances. You can enable keep-alive in your web server settings or in the kernel settings for your instances. Keep-alive, when enabled, enables the load balancer to reuse connections to your instance, which reduces the CPU utilization. To ensure that the load balancer is responsible for closing the connections to your instance, make sure that the value you set for the HTTP keep-alive time is greater than the idle timeout setting on your load balancer.

My current dropwizard configuration.yml file is

```
server:
  maxThreads: 100
  maxQueuedRequests: 10
  applicationContextPath: /e2e
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080

  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
```

My ELB idle timeout is set to 60 seconds. But reading [this](https://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/configuration.html) I found that default dropwizard application timeout is 0ms. How can I configure `Keep-alive` configuration for my dropwizard application?

Comment: `keep-alive` is an old HTTP/1.0 concept.  HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 do not have `keep-alive` in their specs.  Both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 are persistent by default.

Comment: what is your dropwizard version

Comment: @AashraiRavooru my dropwizard version is 1.3.0

Comment: Are these 5XX mostly 504's?

Comment: @AashraiRavooru these are all 502 errors.

Comment: The keep-alive value in the config reference you linked to is for the dropwizard-client, not the application.  Did you ever get to the bottom of this problem?

Comment: @Adi were you able to find solution for this ? we're facing the same issue in our project. not sure if it would make sense to reduce load balancer's keep alive time.